# Overriding inherited fields in Domain classes

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, grails

I have a hierarchy of objects define as follows:

```
class Request {

    RequestType type 
}

class CableRequest extends Request {

    RequestType type = RequestType.Cable
}
```

Hibernate complains with:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: duplicate method: getType

What is the right way to preset defaults (or override fields) in the inherited classes?

**Update**:
So apparently this works fine if the property is marked as Transient... Is there another way to set these the Groovy way without overriding getters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Request {

    RequestType type 
}

class CableRequest extends Request {

    RequestType getType() {
        RequestType.Cable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Don, yeah I started going that rout of overriding setters too - and then I thought - well whats the point? What does the object hierarchy buys me here? Don't I get the same if I just set a type field on the parent and set it appropriately in a service class when creating a new instance. What is the point of single table class hierarchy if you use service classes to manage what happens to your domain classes?